# Github - Travis-CI validation fails - Workstation change

Tags: validation, github, lua, worker, travis-ci

I am actually facing to some strange issue.
I am maintaining some Lua projects of mine, hosted at Github.
I have recently discovered that it's fairly possible to achieve Lua-Testing with Travis-CI validation service. It simply consists of writing tests specs, to be run with a unit testing library (I am using [Telescope](http://norman.github.com/telescope/)), and then fool Travis worker, faking Erlang.

For instance, I have successfully included Travis in this project: see [30log](https://github.com/Yonaba/30log) - [Travis YAML](https://github.com/Yonaba/30log/blob/master/.travis.yml) file here.

I'd like to point out that I am using GNU-bash (v1.7.10) on my workstation (running under Windows 7 x86) to commit, and then push on remote repos.

Everything went fine. Until I switched to a new workstation (WIndows 7, x64). I basicallly installed Gnu-Bash, then I just copied-paste some files from the previous workstation (that is, **.ssh** folder containing rsa_pub keys, the **.bash_history** file, the global **.gitconfig** file and the **folder containing all my on-going projects sources**) on the new workstation.I made some commits, and I pushed them successfuly. But then any build tests from Travis-CI are now failing, the workers report that some files cannot be found.
Here is the [log report from Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/Yonaba/30log), for instance:

> Using worker: bluebox-jvm-otp.worker.travis-ci.org:travis-jvm-10 
>   $ cd ~/builds
>  $ export LUA=""
>  $ git clone --branch=master
>   --depth=100 --quiet
>  git://github.com/Yonaba/30log.git Yonaba/30log
>  $ cd Yonaba/30log
>  $ git checkout -qf
>   0b60646339e65df0f79ce66b6a76c9b825ba5032
>  $ source
>   ~/otp/R14B04/activate
>   -bash: /home/travis/otp/R14B04/activate: No such file or directory
>  Done. Build script exited with: 1

The problem is **certainly not related to the code itself**, as **specs tests are all passing fine**, running them with the test suite (Telescope) locally on my workstation. It just seems travis's worker is failing to find some key file to process the new commits correctly, and then reports that fail.

Any thoughts about what's going on, and how to fix that issue ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I kinda solved it.
I just had to regenerate my ssh credentials (keys) on my new workstation, and I registered them on my Github account. Then, after some further commits, all builds passed successfully with Travis's Erlang worker.
Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, I would, but actually I have to wait for 2 days, counting from the date of the post, before validating my own answer as accepted. Right now, 9 hrs to go. :)

Comment: Ah. I am not familiar with SO's rules. I guess I'll have to look more closely at those.